# Writing in closed form this nasty expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form

hi I have to write the following in closed form,

$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_1 v_{2}v_{1}+ a_1v_{3}v_{1}+ a_2v_{3}v_{2}+a_2v_{1}v_{2}+ a_3v_{1}v_{3}+a_3v_{2}v_{3}$$

$$ \sum_{(i,j)\in \mathcal{S}} a_i(1+ v_{j}v_{i})$$ where
 $$\mathcal{S}= \{ (i,j) \in \mathbb{Z}^2: i \neq j, 1\leq i,j \leq n=3 \}$$ in this case.

But I am not sure if it's correct, I think its not as it will give
$$2 a_1 + 2a_2 + 2a_3 + a_1 v_{2}v_{1}+ a_1v_{3}v_{1}+ a_2v_{3}v_{2}+a_2v_{1}v_{2}+ a_3v_{1}v_{3}+a_3v_{2}v_{3}$$

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? or maybe its correct. Thanks

Comment: i think instead of 2 it should be $n-1$ if i follow the answer I provided above $$ \sum_{(i,j)\in \mathcal{S}} a_i(\frac{1}{n-1}+ v_{j}v_{i})$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?$$ \sum_{(i,j)\in \mathcal{S}} a_i\left(\frac12+ v_{j}v_{i}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, so do you agree that my closed form above is not correct?

Comment: @GeorgeSmith: Yes, I do.

Comment: Thanks again, do you think there is any other way of writing it or our approach (your solution)like this is the best?

Comment: @GeorgeSmith: I don't have any other ideas.